# Is $x \nmid y$ the same meaning as $y = xq +1$ for some integer q?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

I want to prove a statement wish states: if $p\mid abc$ and $p\nmid a$ and $p\nmid b$, then $p\mid c$ where $p, a, b, c$ are fixed integers.

can I use something of the form $\exists q \in \mathbb{Z}, y = xq +1$ to my proof? Is this the same as "p does not divide y" or would this be correct to use as the definition of "does not divide" ?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). You will easily find a counterexample showing that it is not the same.

Comment: $3$ does not divide $5$. But $5$ is not of the form $3q+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll make an observation and ask a question: if $x,y,q$ are integers and $r$ is an integer with $0 \le r < |x|$, then $q$ is the quotient of the division $\dfrac{y}{x}$ and $r$ is the remainder.

If $y$ is not a multiple of $x$, is the remainder of the division $\dfrac yx$ necessarily going to equal $1$?

Comment: No. if we take 10 divided by 4, we get a remainder of 2.